# How fill to solid edges in a coloring book app

Tags: delphi, firemonkey

I am trying to create a coloring book app. The [FMX Paint Demo](https://github.com/FMXExpress/Firemonkey) is pretty good, but the Fill function is all or nothing.

My idea is to get [un-colored pictures](https://www.justcolor.net/nature/landscapes/?image=landscapes__coloring-heavenly-landscape__1) and paint the white spaces.

How can I fill to the edge of a drawn shape?

Comment: VCL's `TCanvas` has a [`FloodFill()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.Graphics.TCanvas.FloodFill) method for this very purpose, but I don't see an equivalent method in [FMX's `TCanvas`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/FMX.Graphics.TCanvas_Methods). You will probably have to use the [`FillPath()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/FMX.Graphics.TCanvas.FillPath) or [`FillPolygon()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/FMX.Graphics.TCanvas.FillPolygon) method, but that means you would first have to manually define the area to be filled.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there an equivalent to FloodFill in FMX for a TBitmap?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22813461/is-there-an-equivalent-to-floodfill-in-fmx-for-a-tbitmap)

Comment: I have been trying to use the FloodFill procedure from the "Possible duplicate" but I get '"E2037 Declaration of 'FloodFill' differs from previous declaration'. Even if I copy the params from the interface to the implementation. ??

Comment: I made some corrections to the code of @albertanugerah. In my simple test it works OK now.